# How can I get Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) to initialise and optional relationships collection with an empty list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

Accessing Neo4j in Kotlin using SDN, I have an entity with relationships which I'm only using to read from the db. Looks a bit like this:

```kotlin
@NodeEntity
class Parent() {
    @Relationship(type = "CHILD_OF", direction = Relationship.INCOMING)
    lateinit var children: List<Child>
    ...
```

I'm using a custom query with an optional match to retrieve these objects. It looks like this (the actual query is more complex, but this is the problematic part):

```
MATCH (parent:Parent) WHERE ID(parent) IN $parentIds
OPTIONAL MATCH (parent)<-[r1:CHILD_OF]-(child:Child)
RETURN DISTINCT parent, child, r1
```

When there are children related to the parent returned by the query, it works fine. However, when the Parent has no children, and I try to access `parentObject.children`, I get:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property children has not been initialized
```

What I'd like to happen is, when there are no related `Child` entities returned by the query, the `children` field should be an empty list instead of being unset.

Is there a way for me to tell the Cypher query or SDN to do that?

Answer (score 0):

This *can* be solved by setting a value to the field upon construction like this:

```kotlin
var children: List<Child> = emptyList() // Default value used when there's no children
```

I far prefer the `lateinit var` approach, though, so if there's a way to make it work I'd like to know what it is.

Comment: I believe, There is no way except writing your own getter/setter and there initializing it